# Set response encoding with HttpClient 3.1

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

I'm using `org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient` and need to setup response encoding (for some reason server returns incorrect encoding in Content-Type). My way is to get response as raw bytes and convert to `String` with desired encoding. I'm wondering if there is some better way to do this (eg. setup HttpClient). Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a better answer using `HttpClient` 3.x APIs.

The HTTP 1.1 spec says clearly that a client "must" respect the character set specified in the response header, and use ISO-8859-1 if no character set is specified.  The `HttpClient` APIs are designed on the assumption that the programmer wants to conform to the HTTP specs.  Obviously, you need to break the rules in the spec so that you can talk to the non-compliant server.  Not withstanding, this is not a use-case that the API designers saw a need to support explicitly.

If you were using the `HttpClient` 4.x, you could write your own `ResponseHandler` to convert the body into an `HttpEntity`, ignoring the response message's notional character set.

Answer (score 2):

A few notes:

1. Server serves data, so it's up to server to serve it in an appropriate format. So response encoding is set by server not client. However, client could suggest to server what format it would like via [Accept and Accept-Charset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields):

   ```
   Accept: text/plain
   Accept-Charset: utf-8
   ```

   However, http servers usually do not convert between formats.
2. If option 1. does not work, then you should look at the configuration of the server.
3. When String is sent as raw bytes (and it always is, because this is what networks transmit), there is always the encoding defined. Since server produces this raw bytes, it defines the encoding. So, you can not take raw bytes and use encoding of your choice to create a String. You must use encoding that was used when converted from String to bytes.

Comment: Hi, I don't have server under my control and it returns wrong enconding in Content-Type attribute (`HttpClient.getResponseBodyAsString()` takes encoding from Content-Type attribute in response headers). I've tried setup Accept and Accept-Charset as you mention in request headers but it doesn't help me. Obiviously it's something wrong on server but I'm not owner so I cannot make changes on it.

Comment: Thx ;). Anyway, why are you bothered by character encoding? In java you can take raw bytes with any encoding and produce a String from it.

Comment: I just don't like the way of breaking API rules, so I want to know possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not really knowing HttpClient, only reading the API.

I would use the execute method returning a HttpResponse, then `.getEntity().getContent()`. This is a pure byte stream, so if you want to ignore the encoding told by the server, you can simply wrap your own InputStreamReader around it.

---

Okay, looks like I had the wrong version (obviously, there are too much `HttpClient` classes out there).

But same as before, just located on other classes: the `HttpMethod` has a `getResponseBodyAsStream()` method, around which you can now wrap your own InputStreamReader. (Or get the whole array at once, if it is not too big, and convert it to String, as you wrote.)

I think trying to change the response and letting the HttpClient analyze it is not the right way here.

---

I suggest sending a message to the server administrator/webmaster about the wrong charset, though.

Answer (score 0):

Greetings folks,

Jus in case someone finds this post googling for setting HttpClient to write in UTF-8.

This line of code should be handy...

```
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Best

Comment: Hi, thanks for comment. Could you please post full source where is clear what object `response` is.

Comment: Greetings, Thanks! I think I should be enough to say HttpServletResponse response

Comment: Hi, I'm using Apache HttpClient to download data. I'm not working with `Servlet` so there's no `HttpServletResponse`.